# Wrap multiple span tags within specific div using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have HTML code like this:

```
<li class="recipe-ingredient">
<span class="recipe-ingredient-quantity-unit">
<span data-original="" data-fraction="" data-normalized="0" class="recipe-ingredient-quantity recipe-ingredient-quantity"></span> 
<span data-original="" class="recipe-ingredient-unit recipe-ingredient-unit"></span>
</span> 
<span class="recipe-ingredient-name recipe-ingredient-name"><a href="/ingredient/water/">water</a></span> 
<span class="recipe-ingredient-notes recipe-ingredient-notes">For Kneading</span>
</li>
```

Using `preg_replace`, I want to wrap first set of `<span>` within one `<div>` and last two sets of `<span>` within another `<div>`, so my final outcome would be:

```
<li class="recipe-ingredient">
<div class="ing-qt-unit">
<span class="recipe-ingredient-quantity-unit">
<span data-original="" data-fraction="" data-normalized="0" class="recipe-ingredient-quantity recipe-ingredient-quantity"></span> 
<span data-original="" class="recipe-ingredient-unit recipe-ingredient-unit"></span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="ing-name-notes">
<span class="recipe-ingredient-name recipe-ingredient-name"><a href="/ingredient/water/">water</a></span> 
<span class="recipe-ingredient-notes recipe-ingredient-notes">For Kneading</span>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This first one should catch the first set:

```
<span class[^>]+>(?:[^<]+<[^>]+>[^<]*<[^>]+>)*[^<]*</span>
```

And this one should catch the second set:

```
<span class[^>]+>(?:[^<]*<[^>]+>[^<]+<[^>]+>)*[^<]*</span>
```

Use it like this to avoid escaping:

```
$re = "@<span class[^>]+>(?:[^<]*<[^>]+>[^<]+<[^>]+>)*[^<]*</span>@im";
```

The replacement should be something like `"<div class="ing-name-notes">$0</div>"`.